# In Java, to use the "super" keyword, do I have to import the target class?

Tags: java, super, superclass

When, in a constructor, we use the super keyword, do we have to import the class the super refers to (when super doesn't refer to Object)?

```
class A extends ... {
    A() {
        super(); // do we need to import the class super refers to?
    }
}
```

Comment: If you extend it you have already imported it (if it is in a different package)

Comment: I was thinking of the case where you access the super of the super. But Java doesn't allow that kind of access.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, because it is in the `extends` clause.

The `super()` itself requires no imports, but for it to make sense you need a superclass. You don't need to import it, of course, if it is from `java.lang`

Comment: actually, no, because you can qualify it in the extends part (e.g. `class A extends com.example.B {`) in which case you can use `super` without having imported `com.example.B`.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to import the super class if it is not in the same package or it is in java.lang. If the base class is not available, `super()` doesn't work anyway.